# Does bounds-checking logic occur in MSIL or machine code

Tags: .net, jit, cil

I've just started to dabble in the wonderful world of MSIL, but I can't seem to find any answers here about where bounds-checking occurs.  Does the C# compiler insert MSIL instructions that perform bounds-checking, or does the MSIL JIT compiler insert them for all applicable MSIL instructions when translating those to machine code?

The reason I ask is because I need to know whether or not I need to add those instructions when I generate functions using MSIL directly.

EDIT: After receiving one answer and attempting to validate, it appears to be incorrect.  The following code actually fails.  Stepping through the debugger reveals that the second test writes beyond the array bounds, and the third test does much worse:

```
static class ArrayExtensions
{
#if false
    public static void ClearRangeReferenceImplementation(byte[] buffer, int offset, int byteCount)
    {
        for (int current = offset; current < offset + byteCount; ++current)
        {
            buffer[current] = 0;
        }
    }
#endif
    private static readonly Action<IntPtr, int, int> MemclearRaw = InitMemclearRaw();
    private static Action<IntPtr, int, int> InitMemclearRaw()
    {
        DynamicMethod memclearMethod = new DynamicMethod("Memclear", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, CallingConventions.Standard, null, new Type[] { typeof(IntPtr), typeof(int), typeof(int) }, typeof(this), true);
        ILGenerator il = memclearMethod.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Add);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Initblk);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        return (Action<IntPtr, int, int>)memclearMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<IntPtr, int, int>));
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Clears the specified range of the specified buffer in the most optimal manner available without resorting to PInvoke or inline assembly.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="buffer">The buffer to acted upon.</param>
    /// <param name="offset">The offset in the buffer where the clearing is to start.</param>
    /// <param name="count">The number of bytes to be cleared.</param>
    public static void ClearRange(this byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (count == 0) return;
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        try
        {
            MemclearRaw(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), offset, count);
        }
        finally
        {
            handle.Free();
        }
    }
}
[TestClass]
public class TestArrayExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Performs failure tests on <see cref="ArrayExtensions.ClearRange"/>.
    /// </summary>
    [TestMethod]
    public void Array_ClearRangeExceptions()
    {
        byte[] b = Rand.NewBytes(0, 100);
        AssertExceptionClearRange(null, 0, b.Length, typeof(NullReferenceException));
        b = Rand.NewBytes(0, 100);
        AssertExceptionClearRange(b, 0, b.Length + 1, typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException));
        b = Rand.NewBytes(0, 100);
        AssertExceptionClearRange(b, 0, -1, typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException));
        b = Rand.NewBytes(0, 100);
        AssertExceptionClearRange(b, -1, b.Length, typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException));
    }

    private static void AssertExceptionClearRange(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, Type exceptionType)
    {
        try
        {
            ArrayExtensions.ClearRange(buffer, offset, count);
            Assert.Fail("ArrayExtensions.ClearRange did not throw the expected exception!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(exceptionType, ex.GetType());
        }
    }
```

It appears that the MSIL only does null pointer checking, NOT bounds checking.

I'm currently using VS2012 and targeting .NET Framework 4.5.1 if that makes any difference.

Comment: It is not in the MSIL, the jitter generates the machine code to do the bounds check.  And the code that generates the exception.  And knows how to *omit* that code when it can tell that the index can never be out of bounds, the ultimate reason why it is not in the MSIL.

Comment: @HansPassant: that doesn't appear to be the case.  Please validate with the code above.

Comment: Hard to see what you are trying to prove, neither the C# nor the VB.NET compiler ever generate OpCodes.Initblk.  It is not a verifiable instruction.  The C++/CLI compiler can use it for unmanaged C++ code.

Comment: @HansPassant: Are you saying that most MSIL instructions do bounds-checking, but this one doesn't?  Is there some way to know which do and don't?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62bwd2yd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The C# compiler does very little optimization.

All the magic happens in the JIT which generates the machine code.

To answer the question, if you generate similar code to what C# or VB.NET does (iow the JIT can determine this is some form of `for` loop, etc), it will work.